# Get app name from its Appx Package Name | PowerShell

Tags: powershell

To get the package name of an UWP app:

`(Get-AppxPackage "Microsoft.WindowsStore").Name`

But what if you want to get the actual name of the app (which is displayed in Start menu).
Ex: Microsoft Store.

Is there a way for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the display name from the package manifest:

```
$manifest = Get-AppxPackage 'Microsoft.WindowsStore' |Get-AppxPackageManifest

$displayName = $manifest.Package.Properties.DisplayName
```

`$displayName` now contains the display name `Microsoft Store`